# How to remove empty string ("") in string

Tags: r

I encountered a strange problem while web scraping using rvest.

I scraped the following name: `"Ab­dich­ter/in EFZ"` which at first looked normal. However, when I wrote the file to a csv I found "-" between the letters. In Excel, the word looked like this: `Ab-­dich-ter/in EFZ`.

So I did a `str_split(x, "")` and found that the string actually looked like this:

```
c("A", "b", "­", "d", "i", "c", "h", "­", "t", "e", "r", "/", "i", "n", " ", "E", "F", "Z")
```

I tried to get the empty strings out of the string but I did not manage. I tried:

```
my_string <- str_split(my_string , "")
```

and then

```
paste0(my_string[my_string != ""])
```

but this did not help.

Therefore, I wonder:

1. How did the empty strings get into that string, and
2. how do I get it out again.

Edit: This is the [webpage](https://berufskunde.com/ausbildungsberufe/ausbildung-abdichter.html).

And here is how I got the string:

```
library(rvest)

read_html("https://berufskunde.com/ausbildungsberufe/ausbildung-abdichter.html", encoding = "UTF-8") %>% 
  html_nodes(".section") %>% 
  html_nodes(".text-rot") %>% 
  html_text()
```

Comment: Try with `x[nzchar(x)]`

Comment: @ akrun, thanks. But it does not work.

Comment: I think your `""` is different character.  You may need `v1[trimws(v1) != "­"]`  Here 'v1' is the split character vector

Comment: One possible issue could be "" compared to " " (space inbetween the two quotes).  For me, in many cases I need to use " "

Comment: No, it is not a space character.

Comment: you can try x[grepl("[[:alnum:]]|/", x)] It returns all elements that contain a letter or digit plus the slash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The string you’re observing is not the empty string but a [SOFT HYPHEN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen) (U+00AD) character. It is supposed to be only displayed when a word is broken across lines, but some editors don’t cope with it correctly, which is why it’s probably shown when you inspect the CSV.

At any rate you probably want to remove it from your string:

```
str = gsub('\U00AD', '', str)
```

Comment: @Roccer If you know about the behaviour of this soft hyphen character, your description made it likely that this was the case. And since you posted a reproducible example (excellent!) it was easy to verify. For reference, it may also help to inspect the byte values of a string via `charToRaw`, but that only helps if you  know what to look for.