# identical strings from different data files won't match in R

Tags: r, string-matching

I was doing some file merging, and two files wouldn't - despite having a key column that matches (I actually generated one key column by copy-pasting from the other). It's the damndest thing, and I worry that I'm either going crazy or missing something fundamental.  As an example (and I cannot figure out how to make it reproducible, as when I copy and paste these strings into new objects, they compare just fine), here's my current console:

```
> q
[1] "1931 80th Anniversary"
> z
[1] "1931 80th Anniversary"
> q == z
[1] FALSE
```

I str-ed both, just in case I missed something, and...

```
> str(q)
 chr "1931 80th Anniversary"
> str(z)
 chr "1931 80th Anniversary"
```

What could be going on here?

Comment: OK - `Encoding()` shows that one is UTF-8 and the other is "unknown" - So. Weird. iconv() seems to fix it if I iconv one of them. This is truly bizarre.

Comment: I can't replicate with the values you provided here so it's not easy to say what's going on. Maybe compare the `charToRaw()` values for your two strings.

Comment: Add `dput(q)` and `dput(z)` to your post.

Comment: That is most likely not going to help but there might be a "hidden" character in one of your strings. I once experienced that and almost gone crazy as well. It was a soft-hyphen: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57077145/how-to-remove-empty-string-in-string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was a great puzzler.  To answer - to diagnose the problem, `charToRaw()` was the answer.

```
> charToRaw(q)
 [1] 31 39 33 31 c2 a0 38 30 74 68 c2 a0 41 6e 6e 69 76 65
[19] 72 73 61 72 79
> charToRaw(z)
 [1] 31 39 33 31 20 38 30 74 68 20 41 6e 6e 69 76 65 72 73
[19] 61 72 79
```

Oh! Different! It seems to lie in the encoding, which, given that these were both plain ole' CSVs I loaded from, I never would have guessed, but

```
> Encoding(q)
[1] "UTF-8"
> Encoding(z)
[1] "unknown"
```

In the end, I used `iconv()` on q to make it work

```
> iconv(q, from = 'UTF-8', to = 'ASCII//TRANSLIT') == z
[1] TRUE
```

This has been a weird journey, and I hope this helps someone else who is as baffled as I was - and they learn a few new functions along the way.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have non-breaking spaces in your string, which isn't really an encoding issue. This happens to me all the time because alt + space inserts a non-breaking space on a Mac, and I use alt on my German keyboard for all sorts of special characters, too. My pinkies are my slowest fingers and they don't always release alt fast enough when I transition from some special character to a space. I discovered this problem writing bash scripts, where `<command> | <command>` is common and `|` is alt + 7.

I think `stringr::str_replace_all(q, "\\s", " ")` should fix your current issue. Alternatively, you can try targeting specific non-printables, e.g. in your situation `stringr::str_replace_all(q, "\uA0", " ")`. To expose the offending characters you can use `stringi::stri_escape_unicode(q)`, which would return `"1931\\u00a080th\\u00a0Anniversary"`. You can then just copy and paste to get the same results as above: `stringr::str_replace_all(q, "\u00a0", " ")`

Comment: Yup. That is it. I like your solution! Oddly, it's because I copy-pasted directly from View() in Rstudio - which makes all spaced non-breaking! HA!