# R String Encoding best practice

Tags: r, string, dplyr, encoding

I ran into the same issue as described in this post:
[identical strings from different data files won't match in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64656479/identical-strings-from-different-data-files-wont-match-in-r)

This means, i had vectors with strings, that looked exactly the same but when set equal with == returned a false.

Here an example:

```
> allowed_stock_exchanges
 [1] "Australian Securities Exchange"  "Borsa Italiana SpA"             
 [3] "Canadian Securities Exchange"    "Euronext Amsterdam"             
 [5] "Euronext Brussels"               "Euronext Lisbon"                
 [7] "Euronext Paris"                  "Frankfurt"                      
 [9] "Irish Stock Exchange"            "London Stock Exchange"          
[11] "Mercado Continuo Espanol (SIBE)" "NASDAQ"                         
[13] "NASDAQ OMX Stockholm"            "NYSE"                           
[15] "NYSE MKT LLC"                    "OMX Nordic Copenhagen"          
[17] "OMX Nordic Helsinki"             "Oslo Bors"                      
[19] "OTC"                             "Swiss SIX Exchange"             
[21] "Toronto"                         "Vienna Stock Exchange"          
[23] "XETRA"                          
> available_stock_exchanges
 [1] "NYSE"                            "NASDAQ"                         
 [3] "OTC"                             "NYSE MKT LLC"                   
 [5] "London Stock Exchange"           "TSX Venture Exchange"           
 [7] "Philippine Stock Exchange"       "Toronto"                        
 [9] "Australian Securities Exchange"  "Korea Stock Exchange"           
[11] "Kuala Lumpur"                    "New Zealand Exchange Ltd"       
[13] "Singapore"                       "XETRA"                          
[15] "Vienna Stock Exchange"           "Canadian Securities Exchange"   
[17] "Frankfurt"                       "NSX Australia"                  
[19] "NASDAQ OMX Stockholm"            "Mercado Continuo Espanol (SIBE)"
[21] "Euronext Paris"                  "Euronext Brussels"              
[23] "OMX Nordic Copenhagen"           "Swiss SIX Exchange"             
[25] "Euronext Amsterdam"              "Borsa Italiana SpA"             
[27] "OMX Nordic Helsinki"             "Oslo Bors"                      
[29] "Euronext Lisbon"                 "Dusseldorf"                     
[31] "Irish Stock Exchange"            "Hamburg Stock Exchange"         
[33] "Luxembourg"                      "OMX Nordic Iceland"             
[35] "Warsaw Stock Exchange"           "Norwegian OTC Market"           
[37] "Buenos Aires"                    "Berlin"                         
[39] "Hong Kong"                       "Berne Stock Exchange"           
[41] "Johannesburg"                    "Nordic Growth Market"           
[43] "Athens Stock Exchange"          
> allowed_stock_exchanges[1] == available_stock_exchanges[9]
[1] FALSE

> charToRaw(allowed_stock_exchanges[1])
 [1] 41 75 73 74 72 61 6c 69 61 6e c2 a0 53 65 63 75 72 69 74 69 65 73 c2 a0 45 78 63 68 61 6e 67
[32] 65
> charToRaw(available_stock_exchanges[9])
 [1] 41 75 73 74 72 61 6c 69 61 6e 20 53 65 63 75 72 69 74 69 65 73 20 45 78 63 68 61 6e 67 65
> Encoding(allowed_stock_exchanges)
 [1] "UTF-8"   "UTF-8"   "UTF-8"   "UTF-8"   "UTF-8"   "UTF-8"   "UTF-8"   "unknown" "UTF-8"  
[10] "UTF-8"   "UTF-8"   "unknown" "UTF-8"   "unknown" "UTF-8"   "UTF-8"   "UTF-8"   "UTF-8"  
[19] "unknown" "UTF-8"   "unknown" "UTF-8"   "unknown"
> Encoding(available_stock_exchanges)
 [1] "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown"
[10] "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown"
[19] "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown"
[28] "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown"
[37] "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown"
```

My questions in this chaos:

1. What is the best practice to avoid these kind of issues?
   For instance, what should I check/adapt when reading in data from different sources that contains strings?
2. How can I now homogenize these two vectors, so that if set equal, it truly will show me that they are equal?

Any suggestions?

EDIT: I found out that the unknowns are ASCII. However I unfortunately dont know how to "homogenize" everything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `charToRaw()` calls are very informative.  One of your strings encodes space as raw character `20` (the ASCII space) and the other encodes it as `C2 A0` the "no-break space".  R sees those as different, so the strings don't match.

To fix this, you could probably write a little function that converts everything to a consistent format.  For example, to handle the no-break space issue, you could use

```
allowed_stock_exchanges <- gsub("\u00a0", " ", allowed_stock_exchanges)
```

where `\u00a0` is the Unicode encoding for that character; in UTF-8 it appears as C2 A0.  (See a website like https://www.utf8-chartable.de/ for these relations.)

Detecting other potential problems is helped by using the `tools::showNonASCII()` function.  It will identify things like the non-breaking space.  What it won't do is limit itself to only cases where strings look identical but are encoded differently, so it will identify accented characters as well.

One other possibility is to use

```
allowed_stock_exchanges <- iconv(allowed_stock_exchanges, to = "ASCII//TRANSLIT")
```

which attempts to convert to ASCII, making substitutions when necessary.  This will convert accented characters to some funny ASCII version (I see "é" converted to "'e"), so you'll need to use it on both strings before comparison.  But depending on your system, the conversion may not be the same as mine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have any idea how I could put this process into some kind of loop, so that data is read in (e.g. as dataframe), columns are checked, and everything is corrected?

Comment: There are lots of ways, but which one is best depends on the details of the input and  the things you want to do with it.   You'll have to give those details to get a useful answer -- but I'd do it in a new question, since it's really a different topic.