# Trying to understand grepl: why does grepl("of implementation", df$var) return fewer TRUE than grepl("implementation", df$var)?

Tags: r, grepl

Apologies in advance for lack of reproducible code. I have a dataframe named **survey**. One column in the dataframe --- **survey$Q17** --- contains multiple string responses (e.g., "High costs of acquisition    Lack of relevant technology"). I have been using `grepl` to create a new column for each of the possible responses using variations of the `grepl(needle, haystack)` command.

When trying to find the all instances of "High costs of implementation", I have made the following counter-intuitive discoveries:

```
survey$Q17.hcoi <- (
  grepl("implementation",
        survey$Q17)
  )
table(survey$Q17.hcoi == "TRUE")
```

This returns 27 TRUE. However, the following code...

```
survey$Q17.hcoi <- (
  grepl("of implementation",
        survey$Q17)
  )
table(survey$Q17.hcoi == "TRUE")
```

...returns 26 TRUE. The following code...

```
survey$Q17.hcoi <- (
  grepl("costs of implementation",
        survey$Q17)
  )
table(survey$Q17.hcoi == "TRUE")
```

also returns 26 TRUE. Finally, the following code...

```
survey$Q17.hcoi <- (
  grepl("High costs of implementation",
        survey$Q17)
  )
table(survey$Q17.hcoi == "TRUE")
```

Returns 0 TRUE.

This is perplexing. I would think that a longest search phrase in `grepl` (e.g., "High costs of implementation") would be superior to a shorter search phrase (e.g., "implementation"). In this case, it is not. The longest search phrase retruns 0 TRUE, whereas the shortest returns 27.

Can anyone explain why this might be? I have used `trimws(survey$Q17)` to remove excess white spaces before using `grepl`, as I thought that might prevent some problems.

Comment: Have you tried comparing the two df (searching "of implementation" and "implementation), to then identify the row missing in one of them? The difference is likely to be in the string id guess.

Comment: Exact opposite. `grepl` looks for the string as a whole. Hence longer patterns are less likely to match.

Comment: @KotaMori thank you for the clarification. I must have some hidden characters in my string.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68985107/2554330 for a common cause of such problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple misunderstanding of regular expressions and how they work, I'd suggest reading the `?regex` help page.

Regex matches the entire string when no regex separator is used. '*of implementation*' would be "Match any string that contains '*of implementation*'". '*High costs of implementation*' contains that substring, while if you instead use '*High costs of implementation*' this would be looking for any string containing that exact sequence of words. So this would for example not match the string '*of implementation*', because it does not have '*High costs *' as suffix.

If what you want is to match any string that contains any of the words you could use the regex *or* operator `|`.

```
grepl('High|cost|of|implementation', X)
```

replacing `X` with your vector. Not that the space " " is itself also a character that gets matched, so `* of implementation*' is not the same as '*of implementation*'!